# When Activity loads completely with Monkeyrunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

My app has an activity which loads some images from server. So, naturally it takes some time to load the activity completely, as it is fetching images from server.

I need to know when the activity loads completely from Monkeyrunner. And if it creates Error when fetching images from server, how I can know about this Error from Monkeryrunner.

Please advise me.

Comment: How the error is shown? Is it a dialog? How do you know is still loading?

Comment: Basically I am using ProgressDialog to show "Loading..." in my app. So, when loading is completed then te dialog is vanished. I need to know how I can know this from Monkeyrunner. If any error occurs (may be crash), how I can know this?

Comment: @dtmilano: do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be exactly the same as your app but you'll get the idea.
The solution is based on [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient).

I'm using the **Progress dialog** example from *API Demos* so it will be easily reproducible by anyone.

When you press *API Demos* -> *App/Alert Dialogs* you obtain

[image: Progress dialog]

then you can run **culebra** to automatically generate a test script

```
$ culebra -VC -t on -r -o myscript.py
```

edit the script to remove the unneeded Views and loop while progress is being incremented

```
# generated script lines removed for clarity
while True:
    vc.dump(window='-1')
    no_id15 = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile('\d+/100'))
    print no_id15.getText()
```

the output would be

```
Connecting to a device with serialno=.* with a timeout of 60 secs...
Connected to device with serialno=.*
Actual device serialno=emulator-5554
21/100
24/100
26/100
28/100
...
98/100
100/100
```